# SUM of values generates incorrect totals

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing a report to total a specific set of transactions grouped by day however, the total is incorrect.  In the code listed below, no errors are generated but the daily total is off by 11.

```
SELECT
'1,*'+char(13)+char(10)
+'80,1006062'+char(13)+char(10)
+'100,10'+char(13)+char(10)
+'2405,'+cast(sum(trans.QUANTITY) as varchar(18))+char(13)+char(10) --Census events --as varchar(10)
+'9999,'+cast(count(distinct trans.TX_ID) as varchar(18))+char(13)+char(10) --Count of Records (for analysis/ validation only)
+'2420,'+format(trans.SERVICE_DATE,'M/d/yyyy') --as service date of Observation Procedure
FROM PAT_ENC_HSP hsp
inner join HSP_TRANSACTIONS trans on hsp.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID=trans.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE TRANS.TX_TYPE_HA_C = '1'  AND-- Billed procedures
  datediff(day,trans.SERVICE_DATE,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date)) between 7 and 7 AND
  PROC_ID in ('90068','94788','94790','94792','94794','10240') 

group by format(trans.SERVICE_DATE,'M/d/yyyy')
order by format(trans.SERVICE_DATE,'M/d/yyyy')
```

This generates the results...

```
1,*80,1006062  100,10  2405,305.000  9999,90  2420,4/25/2016
```

I double checked my totals by exporting the results of this query into Excel, which also generated 90 records for 25 Apr.  However, the total quantity was "294" and not "305"

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRANS.TX_TYPE_HA_C, TRANS.PROCEDURE_DESC, TRANS.PROC_ID, TRANS.DEPARTMENT, TRANS.QUANTITY, TRANS.SERVICE_DATE, TRANS.TX_ID, TRANS.TX_POST_DATE
FROM PAT_ENC_HSP HSP LEFT OUTER JOIN HSP_TRANSACTIONS TRANS on 
HSP.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID=TRANS.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE PROC_ID in ('90068','94788','94790','94792','94794','10240')
  AND TRANS.TX_TYPE_HA_C = '1'
  AND TRANS.SERVICE_DATE ={ts '2016-04-25 00:00:00'} 
ORDER BY TRANS.TX_ID
```

Results are attached [image]

Not knowing which of these was correct, I recreated the same query in Crystal Reports and once again received the 294 value.  Unfortunately, I have to use the format from the initial query to upload the formatted results into another application.  I'm not sure why the total values are not the same across all three methods and am assuming that I'm doing something wrong in the "cast(sum" statement.

Comment: `datediff() between 7 and 7`? There's nothing between 7 and 7 except 7, so that can change to `= 7`. How are we supposed to know why your total is off without being able to see the data? You've asked the equivalent of *When I add up this column of numbers, they oon't come out to the right amount. I'm not going to show you those numbers, but why is my math wrong?*

Comment: Ken,

The "between 7 and 7" logic generates the same results as the logic "between 1 and 7", only it provides the last 7 days.  The results for the 25th of April were unchanged.  I provided the results in my post and have added them again to this post...

     '1,*80,1006062  100,10  2405,305.000  9999,90  2420,4/25/2016'

Comment: You've added **results**. See my last comment again, paying particular attention to the portion in *italics*. The results are meaningless when you're asking how you arrived at the wrong ones without our being able to see the data as well. Or you could just compare the specific rows you see in Excel, row by row, with the results your first query retrieves and find the disparity.  And no, *between 7 and 7* is not the same as *between 1 and 7*. If you mean *between 1 and 7*, write *between 1 and 7*.

Comment: Ken, my apologies... I transposed data as results.

Also, I imported the results of both queries into an access database to look for disparities by each record but the records were identical.  

Agreed, the between logic is not the same, but my totals for that date were unchanged whether I changed the between logic or used the "=7" as you suggested... I apologize for the confusion.

Same tables, same records, same data but I get different values with the "cast(sum" statement.

Comment: @Ken, in reference to your italics post, I see that I've failed to explain my problem.  Maybe I'm making a mistake in assuming that I have the same records in the first query as I do in the second.  Both returned 90 records but maybe they're different somehow as you've suggested.

Am I wrong to assume that my first query should be generating the exact same records as my second?  There's more than one way to skin the same cat and both queries seem to be using the same database, same tables, same records with the same parameter but one of the queries is totaling the values differently.

Comment: your 1st query `SUM` all records. your 2nd query that export toe excel is only for `distinct` value. Remove the `distinct` in 2nd query and try

Comment: As @Squirrel points out, your second query uses DISTINCT, which can cause rows to be eliminated from the second result set that would be included in the first (which a comparison of the data row-by-row would have shown). For future reference, an image of the data (or code, for that matter) is useless here. It can't be copied and pasted for use in testing possible solutions. Images should only be used when there is absolutely no other means of describing an issue. SSMS allows you to get textual results easily, and that's what should be included in your questions.

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel and @Ken!!!  That was the issue... not sure how I missed it.  Staring at it too long I guess.

Much appreciated - you guys are awesome!